# Event Handling in Source Control VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In developing an extension for VSCode, I want to have a custom function execute/trigger when a user makes a commit using the Source Control menu. I would imagine it something like:

```
git.SourceControl.onCommit(commit, () => { 
    // Have access to the commit object and being able to for example
show a notification with the commit message
})
```

However, I have been unable to find the suitable API to achieve this and am not certain if it is even possible.

Sources I have already looked into are:
- [Activation Events](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events)
- [SCM API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/scm-provider)
- [Source Control API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#SourceControl)
- [GIT API/Extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/master/extensions/git)
- [GIT UI Extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/master/extensions/git-ui)
- I also tried inspecting the elements themselves but couldn't really get anywhere that way

Does something like that exist and what would my options be?
Thanks